# Spark MLib ALS input and output domains

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm using Spark MLib ALS and trying to use the `trainImplicit()` interface to feed it the number of an item purchased by a user as the implicit preference. I don't know how to validate my model though. My input is in the domain [1, inf), but the output predictions seem to be floats in (0, 1).

The usual kind of code:

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="Quantity Prediction Model")
hive = HiveContext(sc)

d = hive.sql("select o.user_id as user, l.product_id as product, sum(l.quantity) as qty from order_line l join order_order o ON l.order_id = o.id group by o.user_id, l.product_id")
d.write.save('user_product_qty')

ratings = d.rdd.map(tuple)
testdata = ratings.map(lambda t: (t[0], t[1]))

for rank in (4, 8, 12):
    model = ALS.trainImplicit(ratings, rank, 10, alpha=0.01)

    predictions = model.predictAll(testdata).map(lambda r: ((r[0], r[1]), r[2]))
    ratesAndPreds = ratings.map(lambda r: ((r[0], r[1]), r[2])).join(predictions)

    # Error is pretty bad because output raitings aren't in the same domain as quantity
    ratesAndPreds = ratings.map(lambda r: ((r[0], r[1]), r[2])).join(predictions)
    MSE = ratesAndPreds.map(lambda r: (r[1][0] - r[1][1])**2).mean()

    print("Rank: {} MSE: {}".format(rank, MSE))
```

Extra credit: When using `train()` what is the input/output domain? Are "ratings" some how expected to be on a five point scale? This isn't documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

RMSE is not an ideal metric for implicit ALS (the original paper suggests a more elaborate evaluation technique). However, you can still apply RMSE to evaluate implicit ALS training results if you map your input ratings to (-1;1) as well.

See https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/597 for details.

Finally, some code to get you started (inpsired by MovieLens example for ALS from Spark):

```java
// RMSE
logger.info(s"Calculating RMSE on ${testingSet.count()} ratings")
def groupRatings(rs: RDD[MLlibRating]): RDD[((Int, Int), Double)] =
  rs.map { r => ((r.user, r.product), r.rating) }

// When using implicit ALS we should treat actual and predicted
// ratings as confidence levels. See also apache/spark#597.
//
// Predicted ratings are clamped to [0;1]
def clampPredicted(r: Double): Double =
  math.max(math.min(r, 1.0), 0.0)

def clampActual(r: Double): Double = if (r > 0.0) 1.0 else 0.0

def sqr(x: Double): Double = x * x

val ratingSquaredErrors =
  groupRatings(alsModel.predict(testingSet.map { r => (r.user, r.product) }))
  .join(groupRatings(testingSet))
  .map { case (_, (predictedRating, actualRating)) =>
         sqr(clampPredicted(predictedRating) - clampActual(actualRating)) }
val rmse = sqrt(ratingSquaredErrors.mean())
logger.info(s"RMSE: ${rmse}")
```